# TortoiseHG "thg serve" won't start from command line

Tags: mercurial, webserver, tortoisehg

I am having a problem executing `thg serve` from the command line.  I am executing the following command line:

```
thg serve 8082 --web-conf "E:\Mercurial_Repositories\settings.config"
```

But what I get is the Web Server popping up not configured and not started. But when I do start the web service from within the Workbench the log shows the following execution line:

```
hg serve --port 8081 --debug --web-conf c:\users\vailla~1\appdata\local\temp\4\thg.lov
```

Which is odd.  I'm assuming that the file `thg.lov` contains the configuration from the Workbench.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thg serve` does not support a port number as an argument. It picks `8000` by default. You can change this value in the Workbench by navigating to File -> Settings -> Workbench and setting the value of the property `Port` to the value of your choice. Just remove the port number in your call to `thg serve` and the web server will start running and serving up repositories based on the content of `settings.config`; the modified command line would thus be `thg serve 8082 --web-conf "E:\Mercurial_Repositories\settings.config"`